# Linking to items outside of the web root

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache-2.4, mod-alias

Here is how the directories are laid out on my server (I inherited this and cannot change at the moment) -

```
/var/www/<stuff for the web>

/home/project/src/static/<some CSS, some JavaScript, etc.>
```

In the grand scheme of not wanting to have duplicate files in different directories I tried to include some files like this -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/home/project/src/static/css/<file>.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="/home/project/src/static/lib/<file>.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I get a 404 error for each file I have tried to include this way. I have modified the path to the 'home' directory, attempting to traverse up from `/var/www/` to `/home/` by adding `..` to the beginning of the path string, but no joy.

Then, after confirming that mod_alias was installed, I set about adding a path alias directive to my config file:

```
Alias /home/project/src/static/ /home/project/src/static/
<Directory /home/project/src/static/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Restarted Apache, but still no luck. I tried this with and without the trailing slash.

One other thing that I have confirmed is that `open_basedir` is not set in the php.ini as I understand having it set can produce problems when trying to access files outside of the web root.

What can I do to make these files findable from the web root outside of copying the directory and placing it in the web root folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options... one is just use [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) properly... the first path is relative to the web directory, like if you had `http://yoursite/static` in the browser, you would use:

```
Alias /static/ /home/project/src/static/
```

Or if you don't like that and would rather solve it by changing the file system heirarchy, use a bind mount.

```
mkdir /var/www/static/
```

And then in fstab:

```
/home/project/src/static/ /var/www/static/ bind defaults 0 0
```

And to apply changes:

```
mount -a
```

or a one time mount:

```
mount --bind /home/project/src/static/ /var/www/static/
```

A bind mount is not always the best or simplest choice... funny things can happen, eg. run `rm -rf /var/www/*` and your `/home/project/src/static/*` will get deleted too.

Comment: Ah - I see where I went wrong. I have corrected the paths, now I am getting a 403 error instead of a 404. I started working top -> down by setting perms to 777, but even that does not work...which tells me I still may have the path wrong. If I have the folder relative to my web root and alias that to another directory, all the sub-directories in that remote directory do become available, right? Or does each individual directory require an alias?

Comment: The subdirectories are also reachable through the alias (alias is like that bind mount or like a symlink). And then the <Directory ...> should say what else can be done, and the filesystem handles the permissions (check which user apache runs as and make sure that user can read the files).